# How to run this JavaScript script upon page loading?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a minimal, static HTML page with [voxel-hello-world](https://github.com/maxogden/voxel-hello-world) running in it. For this I've created [this project](https://github.com/dpisarenko/voxel-error).

When I open the [voxel1.html](https://github.com/dpisarenko/voxel-error/blob/master/voxel1.html) page, I don't see anything. If everything worked right, I would see a Minecraft-like landscape in the browser.

I assume that the problem is that the following part of the [bundle.js](https://github.com/dpisarenko/voxel-error/blob/master/js/voxel/bundle.js) script is not executed, when the page is being loaded:

```
module.exports = function(opts, setup) {
  setup = setup || defaultSetup
  var defaults = {
    generate: voxel.generator['Valley'],
    chunkDistance: 2,
    materials: ['#fff', '#000'],
    materialFlatColor: true,
    worldOrigin: [0, 0, 0],
    controls: { discreteFire: true }
  }
  opts = extend({}, defaults, opts || {})

  // setup the game and add some trees
  var game = createGame(opts)
  var container = opts.container || document.body
  window.game = game // for debugging
  game.appendTo(container)
  if (game.notCapable()) return game

  var createPlayer = player(game)

  // create the player from a minecraft skin file and tell the
  // game to use it as the main player
  var avatar = createPlayer(opts.playerSkin || 'player.png')
  avatar.possess()
  avatar.yaw.position.set(2, 14, 4)

  setup(game, avatar)

  return game
}
```

What is the right way to make sure the above piece of code is executed, when the page loads?

Note: Don't tell me to install Node.JS or any other JavaScript server. I want to run this particular example **without** a server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)** and pass your `function` or what you want into the body of the `function`

```
window.onload = function(){

}
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming that all the other js are already in place, and you have jquery available, just:

```
var game;
$(document).ready(function(){
game=module.exports(opts,setup);
})
```